# discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionNotFound: Extension 'cogs.DS_Store' could not be loaded

Tags: python, macos, discord.py

Whenever I run code for my discord.py bot with cogs an error appears:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionNotFound: Extension 'cogs.DS_Store' could not be loaded.
```

Here is my code:

```
import discord 
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from os import listdir
from os.path import realpath, split, join, splitext




TOKEN = 'XXXXX'

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '#')

@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

for item in listdir(join(split(realpath(__file__))[0], "cogs")):
    client.load_extension("cogs" + splitext(item)[0])

client.run(TOKEN)
```

I am currently using MacOS and I would appreciate any help regarding this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`.DS_Store` file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store) is a metadata file that Mac OS has.  You just need to make sure that you're only picking up the `.py` files in your directory:

```
for item in listdir(join(split(realpath(__file__))[0], "cogs")):
    if item.endswith(".py"):
        client.load_extension("cogs." + splitext(item)[0])
```